# Is it possible to insert @Html.DisplayFor using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is the part of my JS code:

```
    switch (selectedOptionIndex) {

        case 0:
            finalChoice.innerHTML = '@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker"})'
            break;

        case 1:
            finalChoice.innerHTML = '@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker"})'
            break;
```

Unfortunately browser renders this as string. Is it possible to use JS as to add this part to my View?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "browser renders this as string"?  Is the server-side code being executed at all?  In this in a .cshtml view?

Comment: I mean that instead of having an 'input type=date' I have a string: ```@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker"})```. Yes, it was executed and this is what I got

Comment: If what you got client-side was server-side code then that code was not executed.  Is this code in a view, or in a separate .js file?

Comment: This code is in seperate js.file.

Comment: That's the problem then.  ASP.NET doesn't execute C# code in .js files.  You'll need to move it to a view file.  You could for example define it as a global variable in the view and then use that value in your separate JS code.

Comment: Ok, sounds promising, thanks for advice!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223422/discussion-between-muska-and-david).

Comment: ok one more question. Is it correct way of doing it in my View? ```<script src="~/Content/Site.js">

        var text = "@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker"})"

</script>``` This doesn't work.

Comment: A `<script>` element either has a source or it has content, not both.  You'd use a separate `<script>` element.

Comment: I did seperate script: ```<script>
    var text = @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker" });
</script>``` but 'ManualDate' got undelined: it shows that it doesn't exist in current context